# Can't get back to ubuntu on Suse

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, 18.04

I have installed OpenSuse Tumbleweed and it looks great but when I turn on my computer the boot screen only shows an option for Suse. I know ubuntu is still on my system because I can access the files through Suse and see all my documents. I have 3 partitions; 1 for ubuntu, 1 for my suse home, and 1 for my suse root files. How do I boot into Ubuntu again?

Comment: Related, possibly helpfult: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/q/88384/301745)

Comment: On a Ubuntu system, doing `sudo update-grub` would probably be enough. However, this doesn't appear to exist in OpenSuse. You would need to do something like `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`. But I'm no Suse expert and this isn't a Suse site.

Comment: @Jos this worked and now I can boot into ubuntu.If you want to repost this as an answer (not as a comment) then I will happily mark it as the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a Ubuntu system, doing

```
sudo update-grub
```

would probably be enough. This command lists bootable disks on the system, guesses the OS installed on it, and shows you the list at boot time so you can choose which OS to boot.

However, this command doesn't exist in OpenSuse. The nearest OpenSuse equivalent is

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

and this has been shown to work on the OP's system.